# HandsOnTable Dropdown with large number of rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, handsontable

I ran into some strange behavior when using [HandsOnTable](http://handsontable.com/demo/dropdown.html) with a dropdown consisting of many rows.

Not all the rows appear the first time the dropdown is clicked.  The second time it is clicked, it works.  It does the same thing for me in Chrome, IE, Safari, and Firefox.

You can see the entire code in JSFiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/nt001ymn/15/

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

  function getCarData() {
    return [
      ["Nissan", 2009, "black", "black"],
      ["Nissan", 2006, "blue", "blue"],
      ["Chrysler", 2004, "yellow", "black"],
      ["Volvo", 2012, "white", "gray"]
    ];
  }

  $("#example1").handsontable({
    data: getCarData(),
    startRows: 7,
    startCols: 4,
    colHeaders: ["Car", "Year", "Chassis color", "TEST"],
    columns: [
      {},
      {type: 'numeric'},
      {
        type: 'dropdown',
        source: ["yellow", "red", "orange", "green", "blue", "gray", "black", "white"]
      },
      {
        type: 'dropdown',
        source: ["Lots of data!", ... ...  "LAST LINE"
                ]
      }
    ]
  });


});
```

**Edit**: In the meantime I'm using Javascript to programmatically click the dropdown twice.  Not really a solution but it makes the experience seamless to the user.

Comment: You need to click on down arrow button, it will work for single click but not for entire cell. Because whenever you click on cell its selection gets occur first and once cell gets selected then dropdown open gets occur. Hence when you again click on it, dropdown gets opened as cell was already selected.

Comment: I am clicking on the arrow button.  The problem is that only half the rows appear the first time.  After closing and reopening the dropdown, it starts to work fine.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use a autocomplete type

```
var lotOfData = JSON.parse($('<div/>').html($('#textAreaData').val()).text());

...

    type: 'autocomplete',
    source: lotOfData
}
...

< textarea id="textAreaData" >...< textarea >
```

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion.  I'll ask the users if they would like to use autocomplete instead.